# Spring Integration: Poll HTTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How can I poll a HTTP web service using Spring Integration.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="in" reply-channel="out"
    url="http://whatever.com" http-method="GET" 
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>
```

The http outbound gateway doesn't support poller like the Twitter one.

Of course there is the possibility to create a dummy gateway to send empty messages and to configure this using a task scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is a pretty clean and nice solution to create an `inbound-channel-adapter`, like this

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="in" expression="''" auto-startup="true" >
    <int:poller cron="* */30 * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="3" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The above one will automatically start(default behavior, anyway) and poll every 30 seconds.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "maximum of 3"; that will send 3 back-to-back messages to `in` on every poll - it it polling the expression, which always returns a message.

Comment: You're right. I meant 'with', but I removed that part altogether.