# Spring Integration poll HTTP/1.1 web service text/xml

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to use spring xd to ingest text/xml responses from a web service using HTTP/1.1 protocol.  The goal is to convert the xml response to json and insert into mongodb.  Here is my spring-module.xml

```
<beans>
        <int-http:outbound-gateway id='HTTPGateway'
              request-channel='input'
              url-expression="'${protocol}://${host}'+'/${context}'"
              http-method='GET'
              expected-response-type='${expectedresponsetype}'
              charset='UTF-8'
              reply-timeout='${replytimeout}'
              reply-channel='output'>    
         </int-http:outbound-gateway>

         <int:channel id="input"/>

        <int:transformer input-channel="to.json" output-channel="output">
            <bean class="com.modules.JsonMapper"/>
        </int:transformer>

        <int:channel id="output"/>


    </beans>
```

and my context.xml

```
<beans>    
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props"/>
    <util:properties id="props">
        <prop key="expectedresponsetype">text/xml</prop>
        <prop key="replytimeout">5000</prop>
        <prop key="host">www.ctabustracker.com</prop>
        <prop key="protocol">http</prop>
        <prop key="context">bustime/api/v2/getvehicles?key=key%26vid=1</prop>   
    </util:properties>

    <import resource="classpath:config/spring-module.xml"/>

    <!-- Override direct channel with a queue channel so the test will block until a message is received -->
    <int:channel id="output">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
</beans>
```

and my test class

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel;
//import org.springframework.integration.channel.PollableChannel;
//import org.springframework.integration.core.Message;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class UrlStreamTest {

    @Autowired
    PollableChannel output;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UrlStreamTest.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        applicationContext.start();
        System.out.println("About to receive message");
        Message message = output.receive(10000);
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        assertNotNull(message);
        //log.debug(message.getPayload());
        assertTrue(message.getPayload() instanceof String);
    }
}
```

when I run the test the message I receive is null but I don't receive any exceptions.  I have log4j configured, below is a snippet of the output

```
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.007] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- InjectionMetadata: Processing injected element of bean 'com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest': AutowiredFieldElement for org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest.output
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.009] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'output'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.009] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'nullChannel'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.010] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: Autowiring by type from bean name 'com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest' to bean named 'output'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.011] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- InjectionMetadata: Processing injected element of bean 'com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest': AutowiredFieldElement for org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest.applicationContext
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.011] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: Autowiring by type from bean name 'com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest' to bean named 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4641439f'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.013] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- ProfileValueUtils: Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [class com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest].
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.014] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- ProfileValueUtils: Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [class com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest].
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'HTTPGateway'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ????  INFO [main] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase 0
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.020] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' of type [class org.springframework.integration.channel.DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry]
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.023] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Successfully started bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
[2015-10-15 16:09:16.023] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
About to receive message
Received message: null
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.045] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- SpringMethodRoadie: Test method [public void com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest.test()] threw exception [java.lang.AssertionError: ].
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.047] log4j - ???? DEBUG [main] --- DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener: After test method: context [[TestContext@450faed3 testClass = UrlStreamTest, locations = array<String>['classpath:/com/bosch/test/UrlStreamTest-context.xml'], testInstance = com.bosch.test.UrlStreamTest@89ec211, testMethod = test@UrlStreamTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: ]], dirtiesContext [false].
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.053] log4j - ????  INFO [Thread-0] --- GenericApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4641439f: startup date [Thu Oct 15 16:09:15 MDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.054] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.056] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.056] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'HTTPGateway'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.056] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.056] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.056] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.057] log4j - ????  INFO [Thread-0] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Stopping beans in phase 0
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.058] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Stopping bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' of type [class org.springframework.integration.channel.DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry]
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.058] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Successfully stopped bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
[2015-10-15 16:09:26.058] log4j - ???? DEBUG [Thread-0] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Asking bean 'HTTPGateway' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
```

I can't find any clues as to why the message is null, it is null without the json transformer as well.  I can hit the url in a browser and get a response.  I'm assuming once I can get a message I'll have to create an inbound channel adapter like in this post 
[Spring Integration: Poll HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360020/spring-integration-poll-http)
but I'm not able to receive a single response as of now.

After enabling TRACE logging for org.springframework.integration I see this between my sysout statements

```
About to receive message
[2015-10-16 09:57:54.748] log4j - ???? TRACE [main] --- QueueChannel: preReceive on channel 'output'
[2015-10-16 09:58:04.750] log4j - ???? TRACE [main] --- QueueChannel: postReceive on channel 'output', message is null
Received message: null
```

Comment: I don't see your test sending anything to input. You should see message flow by enabling DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`.

Comment: From stepping through the code it looks like the request to the url should have already been sent and placed the response in a queue?  ouput.receive() is trying to dequeue an empty queue

Comment: Where are you sending the the request to the URL? It's not in your test. All your test does is start the context and waits to `receive()` a message. As I said, when the message is sent (directly to input or via the http adapter), you will see the message logged (`preSend on channel 'input'` etc). Your stream has a 'time' source but your test sends no data.

Comment: Oh ok I thought spring automatically did that by providing the http outbound gateway bean.  How do I send the request? I posted two different methods of trying to do this - one with the spring xml config and one using the spring xd template which provides the stream definition to the shell

Comment: No a gateway is a request/response - you have to send it a request by sending a message to the input channel. `@Autowire` `input` and `input.send(new GenericMessage<String>(""));`

Comment: Thanks Gary! That did the trick, I added the inbound channel adapter from the other post I linked to and it is sending 3 requests and terminating.  I would like to create a stream in spring xd that will just continuously hit this url, I suppose I could just put input.send() in an infinite loop. I think I've gotten a little confused with spring integration and spring xd.  I broke this question into 2 questions with the spring xd stream creation portion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178407/spring-xd-stream-web-service-responses

Comment: DEBUG logging is your friend; it's customary here to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem - helps others.

Comment: I'd love to mark it as accepted, but its in a comment.  Do I have a way of converting a comment to an answer or do you have to post it as an answer?

Comment: Oops sorry - my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you sending the the request to the URL? It's not in your test. All your test does is start the context and waits to receive() a message. As I said, when the message is sent (directly to input or via the http adapter), you will see the message logged (preSend on channel 'input' etc). Your stream has a 'time' source but your test sends no data.

The http gateway is a request/response - you have to send it a request by sending a message to the input channel. `@Autowire` input and

```
input.send(new GenericMessage<String>(""));
```