# Spring xd stream web service responses

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to use spring xd to ingest text/xml responses from a web service using HTTP/1.1 protocol. The goal is to convert the xml response to json and insert into mongodb. But right now I am unable to get any responses from the stream. I want to do this programatically rather than in the shell, below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringXDTemplate template = null;
        try {
            template = new SpringXDTemplate(new URI("http://localhost:9393"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String name = "test";
        String definition = "time --fixedDelay=5 | http-client --url='''http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v2/getvehicles?key=key&vid=1''' | file";
        template.streamOperations().destroy(name);
        template.streamOperations().createStream(name, definition, true);
}
```

I'm expecting to find the responses written to C:\tmp\xd\output\test.out but no file was created.  I see that the stream was created in the admin ui, I'm not seeing any exceptions.  How do I obtain the responses from sending requests to this url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on DEBUG logging; you should see the time source emit a message every 5 seconds; follow the messages through the flow to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to about the logs on the spring xd server I was just looking for something in the console from the output of the test.  I didn't provide --httpMethod=GET in the definition and it was defaulting to POST.